# Changing image size also changes logo size at the top of the webpage?

Tags: html, css

When I resize image in `<body>`, it also changes the size of the logo in the `<nav>` tag.

I don't think this is the best or most efficient way to code the design for my simplistic website (I have attatched a snapshot of the website [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be3Ai.png))

When I resize the window smaller the image overrides my navigation menu [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNf1x.png).

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>BLONDED</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<nav>
  <span class="logo"><a href="index.html">Blonded</a></span>
  <header> 
      <ul class="__navlist">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">AUDIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SHOWCASE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
  </header>
</nav>

<body class="gallery">
  <img src="img/bdcmag3.jpg" alt="boysdontcry!">
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-family: "SF Pro Display", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 15vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.logo{ 
  font-family: "Blonde";
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
header {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 6.5em;
}
.__navlist {
  word-spacing: 150px;
}
.__navlist li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20;
}

.gallery img{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: The nav - Element have to be in the body tag.

Comment: Still resizes both "logo" and gallery :(

Comment: Don't set the position of your header element to "absolute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your css code to this:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-family: "SF Pro Display", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 15vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.logo {
  font-family: "Blonde";
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: black;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

header {
  /* display: inline-block; */
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* top: 0; */
  /* left: 0; */
  /* width: 100%; */
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-top: 6.5em; */
}

.__navlist {
  word-spacing: 150px;
}

.__navlist li {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20;
}

.gallery img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20%;
}
```